# Can we develop iOS applications using MonoTouch in a Windows environment

Tags: c#, ios, .net, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I’m planning to do an iPhone application on MonoTouch. I’m using Windows 7 and VS 2010. My problem is I did not find any installer or anything that installs MonoTouch for Windows.

My question is can we develop iOS applications using MonoTouch in a Windows environment?

Or does Monotouch only support developing IOS allocation in an MAC environment using C# code?

I do not want to run a VM on Windows and run MAC on top of it and do the coding.
Thanks.

Comment: You cannot DEBUG on anything but a MAC but you can write and compile in many different places. @Partridge has the scenario that I use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Xamarin 2.0 (updated answer)

Xamarin released [their solution to this with Xamarin 2.0](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/introduction_to_xamarin_ios_for_visual_studio) (including iOS dev for Visual Studio 2010/2012). Like my previous answer below, the Xamarin.iOS Visul Studio setup still requires a Mac as a remote build host, so could still be a deal-breaker for some.

*Disclaimer: Visual Studio support is only part of their ["Business" license tier](http://xamar.in/r/SierraTradingPost/store.xamarin.com), and that runs $999 per year, currently. That said, they now have a free tier that allows device deployment and an "Indie" tier that is cheaper for Mac-based-only development.*

I was able to get their system to work fine in beta between a Mac host and a Windows VM. If you have a Mac already but prefer to code in VS, this is a really nice option.

### Original answer

While you would still need a Mac to run/debug the projects, which sounds like it would be a deal-breaker for you, this Visual Studio extension is created to allow you to write and compile MonoTouch projects in Visual Studio 2010.

[MonoTouch for Visual Studio 2010](https://github.com/follesoe/VSMonoTouch)

It is mostly for those looking to maintain the VS IDE experience while developing for MonoTouch, avoiding the learning curve of new keyboard shortcuts and single-pane development. When you get to something compiling just fine, you would need to get those source files over to MonoDevelop on a Mac for any simulator or device debugging and any packaging for deployment.

*Disclaimer: Even after following all the steps on their project page, I was never able to get VS 2010 on 64-bit Windows 7 to recognize the project type properly. I had planned to work in VS 2010 while letting Dropbox sync the files between my Windows machine and a Mac where I would do the final testing.*

Comment: I use this exact setup with dropbox and it works great. You cannot DEBUG on anything but a MAC but you can write and compile in many different places.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot develop iOS apps using MonoTouch on Windows platform. You need to have MAC for it. MonoTouch for iOS development is only available for MAC.

Answer (score 1):

- Using ***Mac build Host*** you can do but you'll need the networked
  mac for developing and debugging too.
- Using ***[Xamarin Live Player](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2017/05/xamarin-live-player-almost-takes-the-mac-out-of-ios-development/)*** now you can ***debug,develop and
  deploy*** the app completely in windows ***without the help of any
  Apple system*** but to sign and release the app to appstore you will
  need Apple System though